# How to test if ActivityIndicator is shown in react native component unit test?

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, activity-indicator

I am learning testing react native apps with jest and react testing library. I could not find how to check if ActivityIndicator is being shown. How do I query for that? Is there an accessibility role? I managed to query by accessibilityHint which I gave like this:

```
const { queryByAccessibilityHint } = render(
    <View>
        <ActivityIndicator accessibilityHint='loading' />
    </View>
)

await waitFor( () => {
    expect(queryByAccessibilityHint('loading')).not.toBeNull()
})
```

But is it OK? And how about showing an ActivityIndicator in a FlatList when using a RefreshControl? I could not manage to set the accessibility role.

Answer (score 3):

The library [@testing-library/react-native](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library) would fit the [query for accessibility](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api-queries#bya11yhint-byaccessibilityhint-byhinttext) that you're looking for.

If you were to use the library I linked you could do something like this:

```js
const { getByAccessibilityHint } = render(
    <View>
        <ActivityIndicator accessibilityHint='loading' />
    </View>
)
getByAccessibilityHint('loading') // If it finds it, it passes. If not, throws err
```

Comment: ActivityIndicator doesn't set anything related to accessibility by default?